# Heap size error when cloning FeedItem of type "ContentPost"

Tags: apex, chatter, governorlimits, heap

We are migrating our managed software from ObjectA to ObjectB. I want to move (via cloning) the Chatter Feeds (Items and Comments) from ObjectA to ObjectB.

I alway run into **Heap size limits** when FeedItems are of type `ContentPost` and contain big files.

I am confused right now as I thought a FeedItem would NEVER CONTAIN but just reference binary data. Isn't there a Chatter File created on those cases?

**As there is currently no way to reparent FeedItems what other options do I have?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our code looked like this

```
for(FeedItem old : [SELECT ...,ContentData,.. FROM FeedItem...]){
   newItems.add(old.clone(...));
}

insert newFeedItems;
```

By removing the `FeedItem.ContentData` field from the SOQL we fixed the problem. Having many MB of binary video data was just to much for the heap. As the Chatter Files already existed the references still worked on the cloned FeedItem.

Answer (score 2):

By "cloning" you are creating a new feed item.  When creating a new feed item, you have the option of specifying binary data which will create a new Chatter File, or, to avoid doing this, you can specify the id of an existing file.

So, you should read from ObjectA the feed items and comments, and get the id of files attached.  When creating the new feed item on ObjectB, you can specify the id and it will reference the same file.

See the RelatedRecordId field [here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)

Note that this is a ContentVersion id (starting with 068), not the ContentDocument id starting with (069).

There are also means to do this using the Chatter REST API [Content Capability.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_content_capability.htm?search_text=content%20capability)